# Problema al ejecutar mi react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

Después de ejecutar npm start la terminal me devuelve el siguiente error:
Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu archivo `package.json`? ¿Puedes agregarlo a la pregunta?